# Indexes on JSON columns are not used when querying with non constant values

Tags: oracle, indexing

I am trying to create an index on a json array column, so that joins / queries on that column would use it.
Let this be a demo value in the column

```
[{"Id": "1", "Name": "Business Law"}, ...]
```

I have created two indexes (neither works):

```
CREATE MULTIVALUE INDEX "IX_MyIndex1" ON "Acts" A (A."BasedOn".Id.string());
CREATE INDEX "IX_MyIndex2" ON "Acts" A (JSON_QUERY(A."BasedOn", '$.Id.string()'));
```

And here's a query that returns items that are not used as a base for any other items:

```
SELECT "OfficialId", "ActArea"
  FROM "Acts" A1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM "Acts" A2 WHERE A1."OfficialId" in JSON_QUERY(A2."BasedOn", '$.Id.string()'));
```

What could be the reason database is not using the index in query like this?

EDIT: I see I am using JSON_QUERY incorrectly, here's the updated query:

```
SELECT "OfficialId", "ActArea"
  FROM "Acts" A1
 WHERE "Changes" IS NULL
   AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM "Acts" A2, (JSON_TABLE(A2."BasedOn", '$[*]'
           ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY NULL ON MISMATCH
                   COLUMNS(
                           Id VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Id'
                       ))) JT WHERE JT.Id = A1."OfficialId");
```

And I've also tried using this index

```
CREATE MULTIVALUE INDEX "IX_MyIndex3" ON "Acts"
       (JSON_TABLE("BasedOn", '$[*]'
                   ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY NULL ON MISMATCH
                   COLUMNS(
                           Id NVARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.Id'
                       )));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JSON_EXISTS? eg

```
SQL> create table t ( j json);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    insert into t
  3    values ( '
  4    [
  5      {"empno":7369,"ename":"SMITH"},
  6      {"empno":7499,"ename":"ALLEN"},
  7      {"empno":7521,"ename":"WARD"},
  8      {"empno":7566,"ename":"JONES"},
  9      {"empno":7654,"ename":"MARTIN"},
 10      {"empno":7698,"ename":"BLAKE"},
 11      {"empno":7782,"ename":"CLARK"},
 12      {"empno":7788,"ename":"SCOTT"},
 13      {"empno":7839,"ename":"KING"},
 14      {"empno":7844,"ename":"TURNER"},
 15      {"empno":7876,"ename":"ADAMS"},
 16      {"empno":7900,"ename":"JAMES"},
 17      {"empno":7902,"ename":"FORD"},
 18      {"empno":7934,"ename":"MILLER"}
 19      ]');
 20  end;
 21  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> create multivalue index t_ix
  2  on t t(t.j.empno.number());

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> select *
  2  from t
  3  where json_exists(j,'$?(@.empno == 7876)');

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 335662370

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |      |     1 | 20500 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T    |     1 | 20500 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   HASH UNIQUE                       |      |     1 | 20500 |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MULTI VALUE)   | T_IX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hey, json_exists only accepts constants as rhs operand, i.e. can't use it when querying with values in db tables.